# Angular deploy to iis server

Tags: angular, typescript, url-rewriting

I'm having an issue with deploying an Angular project to an IIS server. Let's assume my project is named 'angular-iis'. I access my project through [www.test.com/angular-iis](http://www.test.com/angular-iis). The project loads correctly and I can refresh the page. However, when I use a router link to navigate to [www.test.com/angular-iis/test1](http://www.test.com/angular-iis/test1), my web page is displayed, but I can't refresh it. If I refresh, it goes back to showing the [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) page. How should I handle this issue in the IIS Server?

I have tried adding a web.config file to the 'angular-iis' folder, and here is the code inside the file.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/angular-iis/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hashurl</title>
  <base href="/angular-iis/">
  ........
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Test1Component } from "./test1/test1.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '',pathMatch:'full', redirectTo: ''},
  {path: 'test1', component:Test1Component}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Test1Component } from './test1/test1.component';
import { LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Test1Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I hope to have an expert guide me on how to fix the issue I'm facing.If I ask any questions incorrectly, I apologize.